# implementation is in different address

Tags: interfaces, compound-protocol

I have a weird situation. [Here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3d9819210a31b4961b30ef54be2aed79b9c9cd3b) is the contract address of Compound Comptroller contract.

However, the address above doesn't implement the contract. Actual implementation is in [different](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbafe01ff935c7305907c33bf824352ee5979b526#code) address. What is weird to me is, how my function call to the Comptroller interface forwarded to implementation contract altough I pass the address of the non-implemented contract?

example:

```
Comptroller public comptroller =
    Comptroller(0x3d9819210A31b4961b30EF54bE2aeD79B9c9Cd3B);

function getCollateralFactor() external view returns (uint256) {
    (bool isListed, uint256 colFactor, bool isComped) = comptroller.markets(
        address(cToken)
    );
    return colFactor;
}
```

This function call works when I test but contract with address`0x3d9819210A31b4961b30EF54bE2aeD79B9c9Cd3B` doesn't have an `markets` function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that the [comptroller](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3d9819210A31b4961b30EF54bE2aeD79B9c9Cd3B#code) address is a proxy contract. A proxy contract is a contract that forwards the function call to an implementation contract. It is a technique to enable upgradeable smart contracts.

How does it forward to the implementation contract?

Line [2590](https://etherscan.io/address/0x3d9819210a31b4961b30ef54be2aed79b9c9cd3b#code) provides following function:

`function () payable external`

When I make the `markets` function call, since the `markets` function is not available in the contract, it triggers the fallback function, which forwards my call to the implementation contract.